# How to write multiple lists into a text file where each list is written into a new line?

Tags: python, list

I have two python lists:

```
a_list = [1, 2, 3]
b_list = [4, 5, 6]
```

How can I do the following:

create new text file ---> convert lists to json string ---> write lists into the file (each list should have its own line in the file) ---> open the file ---> read each line into a new variable and convert back from json string to python list?

I am stuck here:

```
import json

a_list = [1, 2, 3]
b_list = [4, 5, 6]

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(a_list))
    f.write(json.dumps(b_list))
```

(The json string is written on the same line.)

Thanks

Comment: you want to create a text file (not .json?) then convert a list to json, but write the list (not json?) to the file? Why convert to json at all?

Comment: To write multiple lists to a JSON file, don't write them out one by one. Create a list of lists in your Python program and dump that once. JSON is an interchange format for computer programs. Line breaks are not significant. RFC 4627 says "Insignificant whitespace is allowed before or after any of the six structural characters." If you need line breaks in the file, then maybe you shouldn't be using JSON, or vice versa.

Comment: "The json string is written on the same line" - then add a newline character (`\n`). You seem to be good at breaking the problem down into steps, though if this is anything other than a programming exercise, the above comments are what you should be following.

Comment: @Captain Caveman The main objective is to save python objects into a file, then be able to reload them from the file and use them AS PYTHON OBJECTS again. Saving the lists into a file with the .json extension is more appropriate for that?

Comment: I think that pickle can do what you're asking for.

Comment: Yes, I am just learning to program.

Comment: @Captain Caveman Yes, clearly after researching a bit, using .json is the suitable format for the purposes of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using JSON

first you should put those lists into a dict

```
d = {
    "a" : a_list,
    "b" : b_list
}
```

Then you can dump it into `.json` file

```
json.dump(d,open("file.json","w"))
```

To read/load the files, you can use

```
d = json.load(open("file.json","r"))
```

which will return the original dictionary. ie,

```
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}
```

## Using Pickle

dumping

```
pickle.dump(a_list,open("b.ls","wb"))
pickle.dump(b_list,open("a.ls","wb"))
```

loading

```
pickle.load(open("a.ls","rb"))
pickle.load(open("b.ls","rb"))
```

fyi: I've never used pickle before :)

### Comparison with json

- There are fundamental differences between the pickle protocols and
  JSON (JavaScript Object Notation):
- JSON is a text serialization format (it outputs unicode text,
  although most of the time it is then encoded to utf-8), while pickle
  is a binary serialization format;
- JSON is human-readable, while pickle is not;
- JSON is interoperable and widely used outside of the Python
  ecosystem, while pickle is Python-specific;
- JSON, by default, can only represent a subset of the Python built-in
  types, and no custom classes; pickle can represent an extremely large
  number of Python types (many of them automatically, by clever usage
  of Python’s introspection facilities; complex cases can be tackled by
  implementing specific object APIs);
- Unlike pickle, deserializing untrusted JSON does not in itself create
  an arbitrary code execution vulnerability.

[source (python docs)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

#### tldr

- pickle is smaller
- json is faster
- json is human readably (pickle file eg: �]q)
- json is safer (not relavant in this case)

Comment: Should I close the file after using `json.dump(d,open("file.json","w"))` or does it closes itself just like the `with open()` in python, please?

Comment: @LucasSchwartz to my knowledge none of the functions automatically close the file so it's best to use  `with open()`.